# How to identify a strong vs weak relationship on ERD?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

A dashed line means that the relationship is strong, whereas a solid line means that the relationship is weak. On the following diagram how do we decide that the relationship between the `Room` and `Class` entities is strong. Is it because `Room` entity has a regular key (non-composite)? [image]

Comment: Your statement is wrong and creates confusion, solid means strong and dashed means weak relationships.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We draw a *solid line* if and only if we have an ID-dependent relationship; otherwise it would be a *dashed line*.

Consider a weak but not ID-dependent relationship; We draw a dashed line because it is a weak relationship.

Answer (score 44):

1. Weak (Non-Identifying) Relationship

   - Entity is existence-independent of other enties
   - PK of Child doesn’t contain PK component of Parent Entity
2. Strong (Identifying) Relationship

   - Child entity is existence-dependent on parent
   - PK of Child Entity contains PK component of Parent Entity
   - Usually occurs utilizing a composite key for primary key, which means one of this composite key components must be the primary key of the parent entity.

Comment: What if Child entity is existence-dependent on parent but PK of Child doesn’t contain PK component of Parent Entity.

For Example: Order and Receipt - Receipt is dependent on Order but Receipt doesn’t contain PK component of Parent Entity.

Is it strong or weak relationship?

Answer (score 3):

In an ER diagram, I believe when the relationship is strong, i.e., the primary_key of the parent forms a composite or non-composite primary_key in the child entities, we use a solid line to depict that. Similarly, for the case when the relationship is weak, which means the primary_key of the parent is not used as a primary_key in the child entity, then we use a dashed line to show that.

Answer (score 1):

In entity relationship modeling, solid lines represent strong relationships and dashed lines represent weak relationships.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship `Room` to `Class` is considered *weak* (non-identifying) because the primary key components `CID` and `DATE` of entity `Class` doesn't contain the primary key `RID` of entity `Room` (in this case primary key of Room entity is a single component, but even if it was a composite key, one component of it also fulfills the condition).

However, for instance, in the case of the relationship `Class` and `Class_Ins` we see that is a *strong* (identifying) relationship because the primary key components `EmpID` and `CID` and `DATE` of `Class_Ins` contains a component of the primary key `Class` (in this case it contains both components `CID` and `DATE`).